# Default value for typescript type alias

Tags: typescript, types, type-alias

Can typescript type alias support default arguments? For instance:

```
export type SomeType = {
    typename: string;
    strength: number;
    radius: number;
    some_func: Function;
    some_other_stat: number = 8; // <-- This doesn't work
}
```

The error is `A type literal property cannot have an initializer.`

I can't find documentation relating to this - `type` keyword is very obscure behind everything else that is also named type. Is there anything I can do to have default argument value for `type` in typescript?

Comment: Haha! a very C# dev question

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You cannot add default values directly to a type declaration.

You can do something like this instead:

```
// Declare the type
export type SomeType = {
    typename: string;
    strength: number;
    radius: number;
    some_func: Function;
    some_other_stat: number;
}

// Create an object with all the necessary defaults
const defaultSomeType = {
    some_other_stat: 8
}

// Inject default values into your variable using spread operator.
const someTypeVariable: SomeType = {
  ...defaultSomeType,
  typename: 'name',
  strength: 5,
  radius: 2,
  some_func: () => {}
}
```

Comment: And how do you do this when `someTypeVariable` is injected into a function?

Comment: @Marcus you can [extract function parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#examples) (see "Unpacking properties from objects passed as a function parameter") and give them default values directly. If you are confused, please, make a new question and tag me.

Answer (score 18):

Type does not exist in runtime, so a default value makes no sense. If you want to have a default default, you must use something that exists in runtime, such as a class or a factory function

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** add default values directly to type.

I would suggest the following instead

```
type Person = {
    name: string
    age?: number // Add '?' such that Pick allows you to skip the field (i.e. not force to set))
    country?: string
    readonly createTime: string
    Say(msg: string): string
}

function NewPerson(name: string, options?: Pick<Person, "country" | "age">): Person {
    const createTime = new Date().toISOString() // Here you can set the default value
    const defaults = {
        createTime,
        Say(msg: string): string { // Implement the method
            return msg
        }
    }
    return {
        name,
        ...options,
        ...defaults,
    }
}

const carson = NewPerson("Carson", {age:30})
console.log(carson.name)
console.log(carson.createTime)
console.log(carson.Say("hello world"))
const bar = NewPerson("Bar")
console.log(bar)
```

- [Pick<Type, Keys>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys)

<kbd>[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-utocj1ABFW+R5uUwOcyRHyPZLTyE6fhlzArNZ3IsAITL293KFnyGJB-giSAA)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with TypeScript.

If you simply want to *document* the default, then you need JSDoc:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {object} SomeType
 * Description of what SomeType is.
 * @property {string} typename - Description of this property.
 * @property {number} strength - Description of this property.
 * ...
 * @property {string} [some_other_stat=8] - Description of this property.
 */
export type SomeType = {
    typename: string;
    strength: number;
    radius: number;
    some_func: Function;
    some_other_stat: number;
}
```

If you are trying to actually set a default value, then it has to be done with real JavaScript:

```js
// It all kind of depends on the use case, but here's some ideas.
// When initializing...
someType.some_other_stat = stat ??= 8;

// Or perhaps this happens in a function...
function getSomeType(stat: number = 8): SomeType {
  return {some_other_stat = stat, <otherProperties>};
}

// Or in a constructor...
class SomeType {
  constructor(some_other_stat = 8) {
    this.some_other_stat = some_other_stat;
    ...
  }
}

// When reading...
const {some_other_stat = 8} = someType;

// Or...
const otherStat = someType.some_other_stat ??= 8
```

I find cases like this all the time where I question why we bother with TS in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this when calling the function:

```
// A function with a default parameter
function sayHello(name = "stranger") {
  console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`);
}

// We can call the function with or without an argument
sayHello("Alice"); // Hello, Alice!
sayHello(); // Hello, stranger!
```

[Reference](https://byby.dev/ts-function-parameters)