# Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'.ts(2345)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
type Question= {
  id: string;
  author: {
    name: string;
    avatar: string;
  };
  content: string;
  isAnswered: false;

  isHighlighted: false;
};
```

```
 const [question, setQuestion] = useState<Question[]>([]);
```

I get this error:

```
Argument of type 
'{ id: string; content: string; author: { name: string; avatar: string; }; isHighlighted: boolean; isAnswered: boolean; }[]' 

is not assignable to parameter of type 

'SetStateAction<Question[]>'.
  Type '{ id: string; content: string; author: { name: string; avatar: string; }; isHighlighted: boolean; isAnswered: boolean; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Question[]'.
    
Type '{ id: string; content: string; author: { name: string; avatar: string; }; isHighlighted: boolean; isAnswered: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Question'.
      Types of property 'isAnswered' are incompatible.
        Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'.ts(2345)
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: - change 'false' to 'boolean'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are `isAnswered` and `isHighlighted` properties of `Question` **always** going to be `false`??, otherwise type `Question` should be edited to this:

```
    type Question= {
  id: string;
  author: {
    name: string;
    avatar: string;
  };
  content: string;
  isAnswered: boolean;

  isHighlighted: boolean;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61862235/default-value-for-typescript-type-alias) question about default values in types you cannot set a 'value' for a type because it is about defining what possible values could be not the actual value. A house plan vs. a built house analogy.

It might be possible something similar to [this](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/default_props/) is what you are looking for where you have a constant setting default values (i have copied their example here below).

```js
// using typeof as a shortcut; note that it hoists!
// you can also declare the type of DefaultProps if you choose
// e.g. https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react/issues/415#issuecomment-841223219
type GreetProps = { age: number } & typeof defaultProps;

const defaultProps = {
  age: 21,
};

const Greet = (props: GreetProps) => {
  // etc
};
Greet.defaultProps = defaultProps;
```